# Configuring profiles with StructureMap

Tags: .net, configuration, structuremap

**important**; I'm *really* looking for a [`StructureMap`](http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/Default.htm) answer here. Please don't say how to do it with Windsor, Spring, Unity, or any of [the others](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx).

I'm playing with `StructureMap` for IoC - and basically my aim is to have a "default" profile that defines the core types, and a number of named profiles that override/extend this. I *think* that profiles can do this, but I simply can't get it to work either through the xml or the code APIs. In particular, if I try to load a container for a profile:

```
container = new Container();
container.SetDefaultsToProfile(profile);
```

Then I get "Requested Profile {name} cannot be found", despite the fact that I clearly called `CreateProfile` in the initialize (with that name).

Am I barking up the wrong tree?

(also posted to [user-group](http://groups.google.com/group/structuremap-users/browse_thread/thread/a0f67ba586eb3bcd?hl=en))

---

What I ideally want is to be able to define the *standard* (/default) 
types, and then for a range of different named configurations, 
override some of the settings - i.e. if I had

- global: `IFoo` => `Foo`, `IBar` => `Bar`
- configA: (no changes)
- configB: `IFoo` => `SpecialFoo`

I believe this could map to 2 containers, loaded using named profiles. 
The purpose being that if I ask either container for an `IBar`, I get a 
`Bar` - but configA returns a `Foo` (for `IFoo`), where-as configB returns a 
`SpecialFoo`.

Can somebody give me a clue how I can configure this? Either xml or 
code is fine... I just want it to work. All I need is interface-to- 
concrete-type mappings (no special config/property settings).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick is to make sure every single profile as at least a rule defined in it. If you don't specify a rule (configA) it won't create/see the profile.

Given these classes:

```
public interface IFoo { string SayHello(); }
public class Foo : IFoo { public string SayHello() { return "Hello"; } }
public class SpecialFoo : IFoo { public string SayHello() { return "Hello Special"; } }

public interface IBar { }
public class Bar : IBar { }

public interface IDummy { }
public class Dummy : IDummy{ }
```

You can define this registry:

```
public class MyRegistry : Registry
{
    protected override void configure()
    {
        ForRequestedType<IBar>().TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<Bar>();
        ForRequestedType<IFoo>().TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<Foo>();
        CreateProfileNotEmpty("configA");
        CreateProfileNotEmpty("configB")
            .For<IFoo>().UseConcreteType<SpecialFoo>();
    }
    StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Expressions.ProfileExpression CreateProfileNotEmpty(string profile)
    {
        return CreateProfile(profile)
            .For<IDummy>().UseConcreteType<Dummy>();
    }
}
```

And it will work with these tests:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var container = new Container(new MyRegistry());
    Assert.IsNotNull(container.GetInstance<IBar>());
    Assert.AreEqual("Hello", container.GetInstance<IFoo>().SayHello());

    container.SetDefaultsToProfile("configB");
    Assert.IsNotNull(container.GetInstance<IBar>());
    Assert.AreEqual("Hello Special", container.GetInstance<IFoo>().SayHello());

    container.SetDefaultsToProfile("configA");
    Assert.IsNotNull(container.GetInstance<IBar>());
    Assert.AreEqual("Hello", container.GetInstance<IFoo>().SayHello());
}
```

if you replace CreateProfileNotEmpty with simple CreateProfile, it will fail on the line that sets the default to configA.

Comment: Interesting. I'll try that tomorrow. Consider it a +1 (and possibly "the win") - I'm just out of votes at the moment ;-p

Answer (score 1):

Watch this video, he shows another way of doing the "default" profile and having other named profiles that would act as the variations.

http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/CastDetails/135